# Custom curcit help that has 3 components (Mic/Transistor/motor)

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, circuit-design

I would like to create a circuit that will have a microphone or another sound sensing sensor that will connect to a transistor. When the microphone level goes above a threshold, the transistor lets the current flow to a DC motor. See the attached rough diagram.

- How exactly will the diagram look like (connection)?
- Do I need any resistors or anything else to insert between the components?
- What is an example of exact components needed to build this?

Side question: How do I make that threshold that triggers the transistor be variable or adjustable in some way so I can test the system more easily?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKLAAC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Most audio signals have high crest factors. If you do what you describe, something super loud for short periods of time, take a drum for example, will not make your motor as much as wiggle. You also need to take the spectral content into consideration. If you have some kind of wide band background noise, you should probably filter that before doing anything. Explain your problem without supposing a solution.

Comment: A microphone produces an AC signal, so if you want more than 50% duty cycle on the motor (in practice even less) you are going to need a more complicated circuit.  Suggest you do a search for "sound activated switch" type circuits.  Doing that research will be better than asking people here to do a design for you that bridges the rather substantial gap between what you have drawn and what you need.

Comment: DO NOT describe HOW to do something if you want to know how. INSTEAD tell is WHAT you wish to achieve. Low cost and parts count can be PART of that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far. I am a software engineer so please excuse my ignorance in electrical engineering.... What I WANT to achieve is to turn ON a small 3..9V motor whenever the sound goes above X decibels and turn OFF when below X. In as simple as possible way hopefully an analog circuit...

Comment: Closing due to being a X-Y question.  To make this a real question, you need to pop up two or three levels and explain *what* you really want to accomplish.  Leave out your hairbrain schemes of *how* you imagine accomplishing it.  By asking about details of a totally ridiculous way to accomplish whatever your goal is, you are making it too messy to answer.  *"What kind of apple is best for rotating the tires of my car, or would it be easier with two bananas?"*

Comment: Thanks, sounds like it is not that simple. Ill probably have my company hire a consultant to figure something out.... And ill take a look at this "sound activated switches" as well...

Comment: Actually it is fairly simple, just not anything like the form you are imagining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide this project into three sub-modules:

1. Standard microphone pre-amp (amplifier) circuit, including bias if using an electret microphone. Output should be AC-coupled through a non-polarized series capacitor. Test by measuring amplitude using oscilloscope.
2. Comparator to detect when sound amplitude exceeds a preset threshold. You may need to use a low-pass filter and diode peak detector before the comparator. Depending on how precise you expect this thing to be, you may need a voltage reference, or go cheap and just use a trimmer potentiometer. Use hysteresis (positive feedback) to make the "off" threshold different from the "on" threshold. Test by using an audio function generator, ramping the amplitude up and down, and measuring input and output on oscilloscope.
3. Motor driver circuit controlled by the comparator output. An NPN transistor with a heatsink, along with a freewheeling diode to block back EMF, would be a good place to start. Test by pulling the NPN base low. (If you are using a comparator with open-collector/open-drain output, you need a pullup resistor for the high state.)

Each of those sub-modules should be constructed and tested separately. You didn't indicate in your question whether you've ever built anything before, or what tools you have available. But I would assume you have at least a soldering iron, a DMM, and an oscilloscope, otherwise you won't be able to determine whether the sub-modules are working correctly. An audio function generator would be useful for testing the comparator independently of the mic preamp.

I wouldn't bother attempting to build this on solderless breadboard, because the mic preamp and the comparator will be adversely affected by the parasitic inductance and capacitance. I'd go directly to one of those pad-per-hole blank prototyping breadboards, like the ones that are all over ebay.

If it doesn't perform as you expect, you might need to insert some additional filtering between the mic preamp and the comparator. The microphone's sensitivity may not be aligned with human hearing sensitivity, and so your device might have unwanted response to sounds you're not generally aware of, such as audible 60Hz/120Hz/180Hz hum due to the power mains or a 20kHz ultrasound above your range of hearing. So you may want to add a bandpass filter to pass the 1kHz to 3kHz range, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you´re going to have to do is amplify the mic signal in order to do anything useful with it. The voltage produced by any microphone is going to be a few millivolts, which is not going to be enough to activate any kind of transistor switch.

I presume you´ll be using an electret capsule? If so, there are plenty of simple circuits you could use posted on the internet.

After that, I´d rectify the signal and then your switch. You could also  consider using a relay to actually switch the motor in order to make the cicuit more flexible, ie the motor can be powered off a seperate power supply and is not dependent on the circuit supply.

Answer (score -1):

as mic produces analog signal, you may use an ADC and an encoder. Make an optimized level and design the encoder according to your desired level. Encoder output will turn on your transistor.